# How to fetch the NSSet of all attributes of a one-to-many relationship B of all objects A

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Suppose I have an entity A with thousands of objects.  Each of these objects have a one-to-many relationship to another entity B.  One attribute of entity B is "section".

I want the NSSet of all distinct sections of B amongst all objects of entity A.

Were I to only want the distinct sections of B for ONE object of A, I would use:

```
[A valueForKeyPath:@"B.section"];
```

But is there an efficient way to get this for ALL objects of A? It seems to me that fetching all objects of A and then iterating over this array, performing the above is 'too much work.'  Sure it can be done without much trouble, but I am hoping that my core data naivety simply means that I don't know the trick to accomplish this in one line.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Edit for requested clarification:

Suppose a Person Entity has a to-many relationship with a Vehicles Entity.
Suppose the Vehicles entity has an attribute 'color'.

I want an NSSet of all colors for all vehicles belonging to all people.

Comment: `[A valueForKeyPath:@"B.section"];` won't give you distinct sections of B, it will give you all sections of B.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit -- I've read it 3x and it's still not clear what set you are looking for. Do you want a set of all B entities for a given A uniqued on section? Do you want a set of all B entities filtered by unique sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, and assuming that the A-->B relationship has an inverse B-->A relationship named `a`, your question could be phrased as: *All distinct values of `B.section` where the relationship `B.a` is not nil*. That would get each distinct value of `B.section` for every `B` that's associated with some `A`.

In that case you want something like:

```
// Fetch B
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"B"];
// Fetch B that's related to an A
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a != nil"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

// Fetch distinct values of "section", return values as NSDictionary
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctValues:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@["section"]];
```

Execute that and you get an array of `NSDictionary`. The dictionaries have a key named `section` which correspond to `B.section`. Only distinct values are included.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following managed object class:

```
@interface A: NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *BSet;

@end
```

If you have an instance of **A** called *aObj* and you want to grab all the objects in BSet with unique sections, you would do the following:

```
NSArray *uniqueBSections = 
                  [aObj valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.BSet.section"];
```

Comment: In fact I think that [aObj valueForKeyPath:@"B.section"] would do what you are describing.  The difference between this and what I want is that I need the NSSet for ALL objects of A, not just a single aObj instance.  Thank you for the response though!